# ngx-slick syntaxerror: unexpected token import angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular-seo

Ngx-slick shows the following error:

```
node_modules\ngx-slick\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Host, Input, NgModule, NgZone, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.ngx-slick (D:\dattatray\25o2\frontend\25o2_website\25o2_digital_ocean\universal-starter-master\dist\server\main.js:14620:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

On my Node dist/server, it is showing me the error, but on ng build, it is building properly.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hey, did you figure out the issue?